# Posting comment to Particular news feed Facebook IOS Sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I have been using following code to add comment to particular newsfeed id though I have authorized my app with all the permissions required which are

```
@"read_stream",@"offline_access",@"publish_stream",@"share_item"

      NSMutableDictionary *params1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"comment added thorugh iphone", @"message", nil];
      [_facebook requestWithMethodName:@"comments/NEWS_ID"
                             andParams:params1
                         andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                           andDelegate:self];
```

Result I receive is **The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 3.)**

What am I doing wrong here ? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
  NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Your Comment Text.", @"text",@"NEWs_FEED_ID", @"object_id",nil];
  [_facebook requestWithMethodName:@"comments.add" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Hope it helps.